# join two lists and check for the matched property value and return the required data

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists, i want to compare two lists using fn_cds(List1) with fnctn_cd (List2) and get 'fn_desc' from List2 table. Where 'fn_cds' of List1 are of string[], i.e the data present in the table in one row will be like for ex {fn1,fn2,fn3}.
And the data 'fnctn_cd' will be present in the table is of string type i.e fn1 in 1st row, fn2 in 2nd row and so on. I want to compare these two lists with the fn_cds of List1 with 'fnctn_cd' of List2 and get the 'fn_desc' with the matched 'fnctn_cd'.

```
public class List1
{
  public string[] fn_cds { get; set; }
  public string fn_desc { get; set; }
  public List<List2> List2{ get; set; }
}
public class List2
{
  public string fnctn_cd { get; set; }
  public string fn_desc { get; set; }
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
  List<List1> list1= new List<List1>();
  List<List2> list2= new List<List2>();

   IEnumerable<List1> model = userGroupRepository.GetAllUserGroup().Select(o => new List1
                {
                    fn_cds = o.fn_cds,
                    fn_desc = o.fn_desc
                });
                list1 = model.ToList();

   IEnumerable<List2> model1 = userGroupRepository.GetAllFunctions().Select(o => new List2
                {
                    fnctn_cd = o.fnctn_cd,
                    fn_desc = o.fn_desc
                });
                list2 = model1.ToList();
}
```

I have tried iterating over two lists like below and i did not get the expected result.

```
for(var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
            {
                if(list1[i].fn_cds.Contains(list2.Any(o => o.fnctn_cd)))
                {
                    list1[i].fn_desc = list2[i].fn_desc;
                }
            }
```

> Sample Table structure

```
Table1(list1)          Table2(list2)
----------------       -------------------------
fn_cds                  functn_cd  | fn_desc
---------------        -------------------------
{fn1,fn2,fn3}           fn1        | function1
{fn1,fn2}               fn2        | function2
{fn3}                   fn3        | function3
```

My Expected result should return the 'fn_desc' in list1 from the list2 based on the matched fn_cds[](from list1) with fnctn_cd(from list2).

Comment: I would use the `lcfnc` and `cmpLst`. Any idea what I talk about? It would be wise to name your fields/methods properly. I have no clue what `fn_cds` is. A class named `List2` which it isn't. Do you still know this after 1 year? PascalCase/camelCase. I suggest to start here [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) It will make your life much easier. Also for fellow programmers to read your code. No offence ofcourse, just a suggestion.

Comment: Explanation and naming are bit confusing, why cant you use proper naming so someone can understand that easily.

Comment: You basically want to lookup the ID's in table 1 with the Id's in table 2 and return the description? In this case having a copy for list2 in each of list1 seems a bit wrong, unless each of instance of list1 will have a different representation of list2 (and yes as others have said, the question could have been rephrased in a much better/easier way).

Comment: @J.vanLangen - Yes, i do know the property name should start with PascalCase. But the thing here is i just used the same name which is present in the db table. And the List1 and List2 are not the actual name, i just given this name just for a quick understanding purpose.

Comment: Looking at the sample set for table2, it might make more sense as a Dictionary rather than a list.

Comment: @peeyushsingh - In short i will explain, i wanted the fn_desc from the table2 based on the fn_cds present in the table1. Here the fn_cds are of string array. So every string value in an array{fn1,fn2,fn3} should compare with all the rows of table2 for column 'functn_cd' for matches and return 'fn_desc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I have changed your `List<List1>` to `List<string>` for simplicity

```
        List<string> model = new List<string> { {"fn1,fn2"}, {"fn1"} };
        List<List2> lookup = new List<List2> 
                         {
                          new List2 {fn_desc = "Fist", fnctn_cd = "fn1"}, 
                          new List2 {fnctn_cd = "fn2", fn_desc = "Second"} 
                         };

     var result = model.Select(x => x.Split(',')
        .Select(x1 => lookup.Where(l => l.fnctn_cd == x1).Select(l => l.fn_desc).FirstOrDefault())
                    .ToList()).ToList();
```

This looks rather ugly and feels like a hack though, I think you might have a better construct if you change the List2 to be a Dictionary and re-structure your classes.

Comment: sorry for late, thank you ver much, it works when i removed "Select(x => x.Split(','))" and added .ToString() in "lookup.Where(l => l.fnctn_cd == x1.ToString())" for my same Classes only. Because in my List1 class, "fn_cds's" property is string[], so no need to split.